# Force nginx to answer HTTP 1.0

Tags: nginx, .htaccess

In Apache we can create .htaccess:

```
SetEnv downgrade-1.0
```

Is there alternative in nginx?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: It is no matter now, I solved root of problem and already don't need this, but it is still interesting